# django - "for" loop to process csv file takes a long time

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I created a view where I have a form, I have a input type="file" to load a csv file, but my code takes a long time to process the file, to process a file of 1000 records it takes about 10 minutes, I have analyzed the I code and it takes too long in the "for" loop, insert into the database is not delayed because I use "bulk_create", how can I improve it? this is my code:

```
class AsignacionCreateView(CreateView):
    model=AsignacionContact
    form_class=AsignacionForm
    template_name='gestionAsignacion/asignacion_contact.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('gestionAsignacion:asignacion_contact')
    def form_valid(self, form):
        isvalid = super().form_valid(form)
        csv_file = self.request.FILES['file']
        data=codecs.iterdecode(csv_file, 'utf-8')   
        data = csv.reader(data, delimiter=",")
        next(data)
        asignaciones = []
        for row in data:
            print('inicio de for')
            asignacion = AsignacionSur(
                idasignacion=AsignacionContact.objects.get(id=self.object.pk),
                producto=row[0],
                contrato=row[1],
                nombre_suscriptor=row[2],
                tipo_servicio=row[3],
                total_deuda=row[4],
                corriente_no_vencida_actual=row[5],
                corrente_vencida=row[6],
                total_deuda_corriente=row[7],
                cuota_minima_agente=row[8],
                politica_surtigas=row[9],
                categoria=row[10],
                estrato=row[11],
                ref_anio=row[12],
                historico_ref=row[12],
                ciclo=row[14],
                medidor=row[15],
                lectura=row[16],
                plan_acuerdo=row[17],
                descripcion_barrio=row[18],
                direccion=row[19],
                dias_deuda=row[20]
            )
            
            asignaciones.append(asignacion)
            if len(asignaciones) > 5000:                
                AsignacionSur.objects.bulk_create(asignaciones)
                asignaciones = []
        if asignaciones:
            AsignacionSur.objects.bulk_create(asignaciones)              
        return isvalid
```

This part of the code takes too long:

```
for row in data:            
            asignacion = AsignacionSur(
                idasignacion=AsignacionContact.objects.get(id=self.object.pk),
                producto=row[0],
                contrato=row[1],
                nombre_suscriptor=row[2],
                tipo_servicio=row[3],
                total_deuda=row[4],
                corriente_no_vencida_actual=row[5],
                corrente_vencida=row[6],
                total_deuda_corriente=row[7],
                cuota_minima_agente=row[8],
                politica_surtigas=row[9],
                categoria=row[10],
                estrato=row[11],
                ref_anio=row[12],
                historico_ref=row[12],
                ciclo=row[14],
                medidor=row[15],
                lectura=row[16],
                plan_acuerdo=row[17],
                descripcion_barrio=row[18],
                direccion=row[19],
                dias_deuda=row[20]
            )
```

model.py

```
class AsignacionSur(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    idasignacion = models.ForeignKey(AsignacionContact, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='idasignacion')
    producto = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    contrato = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    nombre_suscriptor = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    tipo_servicio = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    total_deuda = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    corriente_no_vencida_actual = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    corrente_vencida = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    total_deuda_corriente = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    cuota_minima_agente = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    politica_surtigas = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    categoria = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    estrato = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    ref_anio = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    historico_ref = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    ciclo = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    medidor = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    lectura = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    plan_acuerdo = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    descripcion_barrio = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    dias_deuda = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'asignacion_surtigas'


class AsignacionContact(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre_asignacion = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    idproyecto = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    fecha_inicio = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    fecha_fin = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    observacion = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre_asignacion
    
    class Meta:
         managed = False
         db_table = 'asignacion_contact'
```

cprofile:   csv with 300 records

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E4FaKdYtnQI_KMLeAIFaUB7K_uvhEifw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Just try for loop instead of trying to reach every element by number

Comment: Is `AsignacionSur` a django model class? Without any information on what type of object this is, it's obviously hard to say why instantiating a few thousand instances of that class takes so long.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @cemper93 yes ,, I have edited the question and added the models

Comment: Except for the fact that your posted code says `class AsignacionSurt` instead of `AsignacionSur`, nothing really stands out. You may have to run a trace of your program (for example using cProfile - just rename the `form_valid()` method to `form_valid_impl()` and add a new method `form_valid(self, form)` that just calls `cProfile.runctx("self.form_valid_impl(form)", globals(), locals())`). The trace will tell you what methods your program spends the most time in, even all the way down the call stack. Then you can try and work out form there why your code takes so long to execute.

Comment: @cemper93  I have edited the question and added cprofile output

Comment: This part of the code is probably the bottleneck: `AsignacionContact.objects.get(id=self.object.pk)` considering 1000 rows that's a 1000 queries to the database. Few points to consider: Where does `self.object` come from? Is it an `AsignacionContact` instance? If so why do you even need that query? Why not directly write `idasignacion=self.object`?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat you're right , I had read  but skipped it.:  If you are processing the file line by line, avoid queries to the database in the for loop body.